# Google cloud function - trying 2 way ssl handshake but getting error unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: google-cloud-functions, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I have my own clients Private key and certificate which I have put in keystore, and servers public certificate root and intermediate I have created truststore and put them into it. I am trying to ssl handshake but not able to do so. I have below code snippet not sure what went wrong

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                keystore.load(keystoreStream, "mypass".toCharArray());
                kmf.init(keystore, "mypass".toCharArray());
                KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();
                keystoreStream.close();
                keystoreStream = null;
                
                
                TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                truststore.load(truststoreStream, "mypass".toCharArray());
                tmf.init(truststore);
                TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
                truststoreStream.close();
                truststoreStream = null;
                
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
                
                if (urlConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
                    HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection;
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                    //error on below line                   
                    httpURLConnection.connect();

                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(requestData.toString());
                    wr.flush();

                    responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                }
            }
```

Error -

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Can you please confirm if this code works locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a certificate that is self-signed (a Certificate Authority did not sign it) or a certificate chain that does not exist within the Java truststore.

As a workaround, you can add this certificate to the list of trusted certificates of your JVM.

- First you can check if your certificate is already in the truststore
  by running the following command: `keytool -list -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts"` (you don't need to provide a
  password).

  If your certificate is missing, you can get it by downloading it with
  your browser and add it to the truststore with the following command:

  `keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>`

  Alternatively you may refer to this [thread](https://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed/).
- It is important that you see that the correct truststore is in use.
  If `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` has been configured, it will override
  the location of the default truststore, which will need to be
  checked.
- Also,you may have multiple JRE/JDKs and that sometimes might be a
  source of confusion. Hence, make sure the certificates have been
  imported into the correct truststore.
- Check if your Anti Virus tool has "SSL Scanning" blocking SSL/TLS. If
  it does, disable this feature or set exceptions for the target
  addresses.
- Verify that the target server is configured to serve SSL correctly.
  This can be done with the [SSL Server Test tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).
- If the above fails, your truststore might be out of date. Upgrade
  Java to the latest version supported by your application.

Comment: If my answer was useful you can accept ✔ and upvote  :) Feel free to ask further queries.